# Why can't I upload and save images in Django running on Ubuntu server?

Tags: django

So I have a Django application running on Ubuntu and nginx. I have done everything that's required to upload image, and have a template with input fields for uploading images. There's actually no error in the process, but when I save it, I don't see any file attached in the Django admin. Let me show you my code and then explain further : 
 mdoels.py

```
class ArticleInput(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    ...
    img = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="article_img")
```

forms.py

```
class ArticleInputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    img = forms.ImageField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model=ArticleInput
        fields=['title', 'img', 'subtitle', 'contents']
```

views.py

```
def articleinput(request):
    form = DansangInputForm(initial={'authuser':request.user})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleInputForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.authuser = request.user
            
            instance.img= request.FILES.get('img')
            ...
            instance.save()
            return redirect('/article/articlemain')

    return render(request,'article/articleinput.html', {'form':form})
```

articleinput.html

```
<form method="post" class="form-group">
  {% csrf_token %}
...
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-12">
      <div class="input-img">{{form.img|as_crispy_field}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
...
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button type='submit' class="btn all-buttons">
        Save
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My settings.py has no problem, believe me, and I've also done the `chmod -R 777` command for granting permission to all of my users. 
So as mentioned, everything works fine in the whole process. I get no error messages, but when I attach an image file and hit "save" and check the object in Django admin, the `img` field is empty. I assume there is a problem in the `views.py` but I can't see any. Please help. Thank you very much in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a image or a file than you need to add enctype in your form tag

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```